# Windows 7 - media sharing extremely flakey (XBox 360)

Tags: windows-7, media-player, xbox360

I have constant headaches with Windows Media Library sharing, which I'm using to share my video library (a whole lot of AVI files on my computer's hard drive) with the XBox 360. I have the whole setup working, so setup and basic configuration is not an issue.

The issue is that Windows Media Library frequently fails to notice additions and modifications to the "watched" folders. Not only that, but often after I've added something new to the library, it fails to transmit this new library information to the 360, as is demonstrated by the fact that, using that 360, I navigate to my video library and the new folders don't show up in the list.

Often the only way to get the 360 to see the changes is to exit out of "Videos" on the 360, then remove all videos from Windows Media Library, go back into videos on the 360 to confirm that nothing is shared, then re-add a few videos (but not too many) in Windows Media Library, then go back into the videos in the 360.

The whole thing is a real pain in the bum and I really wish I could just add all my videos to Windows Media Library and have it keep watch without me having to kick it, and have the 360 pick up changes without me having to constantly rebuild the library.

Any ideas?

Comment: I experience this same issue and it is extremely. Any time a video is added to my share the XBOX will not pick it up, I also have an issue with it recognizing a "Ghosted" share drive. (A drive that was shared and then removed from the PC but still shows on the XBOX) I read in a forum that having Windows Media Player(Center?) open while moving files will update the share information on the XBOX the next time it is booted. I have tried this and it is also flaky at best. I am going to try @Nick 's suggestion but something non-third-party would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

I Use A Programme Called TVersity as i have the same issue its a pain in the A$$

it sometimes wont pick it up, but a router restart usually fixes that, you can also add RSS feeds + your youtube favourites etc

is a very hand piece of software, the have a few version & a pay version

google it

TVersity

Answer (score 0):

Your files still show because they are listed in the Windows media library. Update your library and they will disappear from your Xbox. Same thing for new files, make sure that your Windows library is up to date and they show. If there is still a problem then go to your network settings and set the Xbox to share all forms of media.